# php if else statement in WordPress - what is wrong?

Tags: if-statement

After i changed our hosting (different php versions)

current hosting - PHP 5.3.3 (cli)
previous one - PHP 5.5.19 (cli)

Some code in our WP site stop working, try to make changes, but w/o any success. "If" and "else" works well, but when i try to add "elseif" it stops working.

Here is my code [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/sPnJX1ud)

thanks

Comment: Define "stops working".  What *does* it do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed { or } if it's longer than 1 line code after. Try add a space like this: "else if".
Good luck! I hope i helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a `;`, I don't know it that was the problem.

Anyways this is the same code (just with some indentation), it should work properly.

```
<?php if($page_id == 35) : ?>
    <a href="tel:111111">111</a>

<?php elseif($page_id == 55) : ?>
    <a href="tel:111111">22</a>

<?php else: ?>
    <a href="tel:333">Other</a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

If that does still not work, you can try to use `else: if` way:

```
<?php if($page_id == 35) : ?>
    <a href="tel:111111">111</a>

<?php else: 
    if($page_id == 55) : ?>
        <a href="tel:111111">22</a>

    <?php else: ?>
        <a href="tel:333">Other</a>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

*Added indentation for clarification purposes*